# What matcher format to use with Capybara/Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest, assertion, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying out Capybara with Minitest as it's included in Rails 5.1. But being a newbie I'm a bit confused with how I should write the matchers/assertions.

I've found all of the following that seem to do the same thing (and all do work):

```
assert page.has_content?
has_content?
assert_content
```

Is there any difference between these or any "correct" way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`has_content?`  is just a boolean method that returns true or false, it is not an assertion so that one's out.

`assert page.has_content?` is an assertion on a boolean method, so it will assert an error, but the error message will just be that it expected true and got false

`assert_content` will assert an error if the content is missing and give you detailed error messages about what failed, so that should be the one to use.

Basically prefer the asssertions defined in https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/minitest.rb when using with Minitest